# Laravel 8 Dark Mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, darkmode

I want to make dark mode in Laravel 8. I can turn dark mode on or off using the icon. When I click the button, dark mode works, but when I refresh the page, it returns to its original state. How can I stabilize this by keeping it in the database or cookie?

Dark mode

```
<body class="vertical-layout vertical-menu-modern **dark-layout** navbar-floating footer-static  ">
```

Light mode

```
<body class="vertical-layout vertical-menu-modern  navbar-floating footer-static  ">
```

I want to change this part of the body class statically and make it dark or light mode.

Comment: Did you use `jQuery/JavaScript` to add/remove `dark-layout` class?

Comment: I didn't use js. How can I do it using js? How can I replace and save class with js?